# Is there a standard way to represent any API?

Tags: api, notation

I want a notation which helps me visualize any API (Application Programming Interface). The best that I have found so far is the Augmented BCNF notation as mentioned in rfc 5234. Is there a standard for this ?

Thanks

Comment: An API is certainly dependent on the programming language. An API for a C++ library is not the same as an API for an Ocaml library.

Comment: Yah but there can still be a way to describe it using a standard notation.

Answer (score 1):

BNF is for specifying syntax. A language-independent API specification is just about semantics, not syntax. You could just use a simple function call notation, like the way TCP is specified in section 3.8 of [RFC 793](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt).